# objective-c release time and bad exeaccess

Tags: objective-c, autorelease

I had a code like this, in MRC, I believe the invoke of [t2 description] will crash the app cos 
BAD_EXEACESS, t has been released, but when I test this, sometimes it's ok, sometimes it crashed,
so here comes the question, is the release operation async?

another question is if we have 2 pointers point to the same autorelease object,
when autorelease pool drains, its pretty much like [t release] then [t2 release], will it be a problem?

```
NSObject * t = [[NSObject alloc] init];
NSObject * t2 = t;

[t release];
[t2 description];
```

Answer (score 1):

Sending a message to a potentially deallocated instance is **undefined behavior**. Undefined means there is no guarantee what will happen. It might crash. It might seem to work correctly. It might make Hello Kitty pop up on your computer. Whatever.

Usually when some dynamically-allocated memory is deallocated, the bytes in memory remain the same. The memory block is simply marked as available for use. So usually, until something new overwrites the memory, the memory location will still "look like" it did before when the object was valid, so if you try to use it as if it were a real object, it is not unusual for some types of operations to still seem to "succeed". Again, this depends on lots of circumstantial conditions like how the memory was allocated, whether an object happens to be allocated where the old one was, the particular system, etc., and you cannot rely on it.

> so here comes the question, is the release operation async?

No. Release is synchronous. But a release does not necessarily deallocate it. You don't know what may have retained and autoreleased it in the time the object was alive. Any API is allowed to retain and autorelease an object. In this case, it is unlikely anyone autoreleased it.

Answer (score 0):

The release operation might work asynchronously, that depends on the implementation. I think in reality it is not asynchronous.
But sometimes the frameworks holds an extra reference to an instance. And this reference might only be released after the next iteration of the runloop, or it might only be released if a memory warning is received, it's even possible that it will never be released. Under the hood the system really tries to optimize memory operations. For example string literals get never deallocated, and immutable strings that you create with these string literals actually point to the same string literals. But that's an implementation detail, and you must not rely on it.

There are basically two rules:

Once you have sent the last `release` message to an object you must not access it. And by last I mean from the perspective of your own code. e.g.:

```
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Foo"]; // 1 reference from alloc
NSLog("%@", str); // good
[str retain]; // reference count + 1 = 2 total
NSLog("%@", str); // good 
[str release]; // reference count - 1 = 1 total
NSLog("%@", str); // good 
[str release]; // reference count -1 = 0 total. Object should be considered deallocated
NSLog("%@", str); // bad. It is no longer safe to access the object
```

If you send `autorelease` you are safe to access the object until you leave the current scope of the autorelease pool (if you don't use your own pools that is usually until you return from a method). e.g.:

```
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Foo"]; // 1 reference from alloc
NSLog("%@", str); // good
[str retain]; // reference count + 1 = 2 total
NSLog("%@", str); // good 
[str release]; // reference count - 1 = 1 total
NSLog("%@", str); // good 
[str autorelease]; // some time in the future, but after the current runloop iteration: reference count - 1 = 0 total.
NSLog("%@", str); // good. because the object will be released later
```

And you must not autorelease more references than you took. Because as said, autorelease basically delays the sending of a `release` message to a later time. It will be send. The auto in autorelease does not mean that the system inspects the object to see if a release is necessary.

---

And keep in mind that those messages are sent to objects, not to variables.

Your code:

```
NSObject * t = [[NSObject alloc] init];
NSObject * t2 = t;

[t release];
[t2 description];
```

in regards of memory management is equal to this:

```
NSObject * t = [[NSObject alloc] init];

[t release];
[t description];
```

When you do such things you should send a retain message and (auto)release it later. I usually use autorelease. E.g:

```
NSObject * t = [[NSObject alloc] init];
NSObject * t2 = [[t retain] autorelease];

[t release];
[t2 description]; // totally safe to do
```

Or to make it more obvious what happens we can split the code into more lines:

```
NSObject * t = [[NSObject alloc] init]; // ref = 1 
NSObject * t2 = t;  // no change in ref count
[t retain];  // ref + 1 = 2
[t autorelease]; // later: ref - 1 = current ref: 2 (-1 scheduled for later)

[t release]; // ref - 1 = 1 (-1 later)
[t2 description]; // totally safe to do because you still have a reference

return;
// end of method

// when the autorelease pool is drained the system sends the scheduled release
// the object is no longer referenced and gets deallocated.
```

---

A little side note: It's good to learn this stuff, but in productive code you better enable ARC. ARC is very stable, fast and in a complex app it will improve the stability of your own code. You have to write less code and you have to debug less. So do yourself a favor and use ARC in production.

Answer (score -2):

I guess the first question may be associated with Runloop:When you call release API , the system sends a  message to Runloop , then Runloop find the function and execute it, instead of executed immediately.

the second question , when autorelease pool drains, retain count of the autorelease object will -1，if the retain count becomes 0，the autorelease object will be released.In object-C ,you  are allowed to send msg to a nil object.

Hope to help you...

Comment: the pointer to an autoreleased object does NOT become nil. It is a "dangling pointer" and messaging an object using that pointer will probably result in a crash.

Comment: first one, its not in the runloop,second one, does NOT become nil